# Get a list of Handles of a process

Tags: c++, winapi, process, handle

I can't get the full list of handles, the stackoverflow user suggested me to give the program privileges, but still the problem is not solved, can you help me please?

If anything, I run the program as administrator. and I get the handles of an ordinary process, not even a system process, and still the list is not complete, I compared it with the process hacker it gave me a list of handles.

**I apply privileges and still can't get the full list of handles...**

```cpp
void SetPrivilege()
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState;
    LUID luid;
    HANDLE hToken;

    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid);

    NewState.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    NewState.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    NewState.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &NewState, sizeof(NewState), NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(hToken);
}

int main(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    SetPrivilege();
    _NtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation =
        (_NtQuerySystemInformation)GetLibraryProcAddress((PSTR)"ntdll.dll", (PSTR)"NtQuerySystemInformation");
    _NtDuplicateObject NtDuplicateObject =
        (_NtDuplicateObject)GetLibraryProcAddress((PSTR)"ntdll.dll", (PSTR)"NtDuplicateObject");
    _NtQueryObject NtQueryObject =
        (_NtQueryObject)GetLibraryProcAddress((PSTR)"ntdll.dll", (PSTR)"NtQueryObject");
    NTSTATUS status;
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION handleInfo;
    ULONG handleInfoSize = 0x10000;
    //ULONG pid;
    HANDLE processHandle;
    ULONG i;

    unsigned __int16 pid = 0;
    std::cin >> pid;

    if (!(processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, 0, pid)))
    {
        printf("Could not open PID %d! (Don't try to open a system process.)\n", pid);
        return 1;
    }

    handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)malloc(handleInfoSize);

    /* NtQuerySystemInformation won't give us the correct buffer size,
       so we guess by doubling the buffer size. */
    while ((status = NtQuerySystemInformation(
        SystemHandleInformation,
        handleInfo,
        handleInfoSize,
        NULL
    )) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)realloc(handleInfo, handleInfoSize *= 2);

    /* NtQuerySystemInformation stopped giving us STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH. */
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("NtQuerySystemInformation failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < handleInfo->HandleCount; i++)
    {
        SYSTEM_HANDLE handle = handleInfo->Handles[i];
        HANDLE dupHandle = NULL;
        POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION objectTypeInfo;
        PVOID objectNameInfo;
        UNICODE_STRING objectName;
        ULONG returnLength;

        /* Check if this handle belongs to the PID the user specified. */
        if (handle.ProcessId != pid)
            continue;

        /* Duplicate the handle so we can query it. */
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtDuplicateObject(
            processHandle,
            (HANDLE)handle.Handle,
            GetCurrentProcess(),
            &dupHandle,
            0,
            0,
            0
        )))
        {
            printf("[%#x] Error!\n", handle.Handle);
            continue;
        }

        /* Query the object type. */
        objectTypeInfo = (POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)malloc(0x1000);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
            dupHandle,
            ObjectTypeInformation,
            objectTypeInfo,
            0x1000,
            NULL
        )))
        {
            printf("[%#x] Error!\n", handle.Handle);
            CloseHandle(dupHandle);
            continue;
        }

        /* Query the object name (unless it has an access of
           0x0012019f, on which NtQueryObject could hang. */
        if (handle.GrantedAccess == 0x0012019f)
        {
            /* We have the type, so display that. */
            printf(
                "[%#x] %.*S: (did not get name)\n",
                handle.Handle,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer
            );
            free(objectTypeInfo);
            CloseHandle(dupHandle);
            continue;
        }

        objectNameInfo = malloc(0x1000);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
            dupHandle,
            ObjectNameInformation,
            objectNameInfo,
            0x1000,
            &returnLength
        )))
        {
            /* Reallocate the buffer and try again. */
            objectNameInfo = realloc(objectNameInfo, returnLength);
            if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
                dupHandle,
                ObjectNameInformation,
                objectNameInfo,
                returnLength,
                NULL
            )))
            {
                /* We have the type name, so just display that. */
                printf(
                    "[%#x] %.*S: (could not get name)\n",
                    handle.Handle,
                    objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                    objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer
                );
                free(objectTypeInfo);
                free(objectNameInfo);
                CloseHandle(dupHandle);
                continue;
            }
        }

        /* Cast our buffer into an UNICODE_STRING. */
        objectName = *(PUNICODE_STRING)objectNameInfo;

        /* Print the information! */
        if (objectName.Length)
        {
            /* The object has a name. */
            printf(
                "[%#x] %.*S: %.*S\n",
                handle.Handle,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer,
                objectName.Length / 2,
                objectName.Buffer
            );
        }
        else
        {
            /* Print something else. */
            printf(
                "[%#x] %.*S: (unnamed)\n",
                handle.Handle,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer
            );
        }

        free(objectTypeInfo);
        free(objectNameInfo);
        CloseHandle(dupHandle);
    }

    free(handleInfo);
    CloseHandle(processHandle);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: edit post please check

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you running your program with elevated rights?

Comment: @zett42 i am start exe without errors, requireAdministrator, the problem is that the handles are obtained but not all, some are not, which I see in the hacker process, for example, the type of process or thread

Comment: Try to run your program using LocalSystem account, e. g. using [`psexec -s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

Comment: @zett42, I still get an incomplete list of handles, it's strange, and I can't get the handles of some processes, I don't have access like...

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs to be executed with SeDebugPrivilege to be able to query handles from system processes and also processes running as other users.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @IvanM1999 Windows processes have a security descriptor and by default you can only use OpenProcess with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access when querying those processes. SeDebugPrivilege disables checking the security descriptor when calling OpenProcess and this is the only way to open other processes with PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE (like your code does) and query their handles (like all other tools).